# Thread-safe collection for rotating number reading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm wondering if there's an inbuilt collection (or any way to make a custom one) in C# that can be used to emit numbers in a rotating/cyclic fashion (see example below), and is thread-safe (so each thread gets the next number in the collection).

Collection with 5 sequential numbers:

`Thread 1 read: return value 1
Thread 2 read: return value 2
Thread 3 read: return value 3
Thread 4 read: return value 4
Thread 5 read: return value 5
Thread 6 read: return value 1
Thread 7 read: return value 2
Thread 8 read: return value 3`

and so on.

Basically, the next number emitted by the collection (when read by a thread) should be one after the previous one, and it should restart from the beginning at the end of the number set.

Comment: Interlocked.Increment together with modulo?

Comment: What will the threads *do* with these numbers. Is it possible that you're trying to reinvent some kind of partitioning mechanism?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point. Think of the numbers as IP addresses. Threads will just use the numbers for allocating IP addresses in rotation, reducing random over-allocation to any one IP.

Comment: Built-in? No. "Any way"? Yes, of course. There are countless possible ways you _could_ make one. What have you tried? What did it do? Why did that not meet your goal?

Comment: Thanks @muzzlator, `Interlocked.Increment` is what I was looking for to achieve a round-robin mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can greate a method, that will return infinate enumerable:

```
    private object _lock = new object();
    private int i = 0;
    private int max = 6;

    public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                i++;
                if (i == max)
                    i = 1;
                yield return i;
            }
        }

    }
```

And get them:

```
var numbers = GetNumbers().Take(1000).ToArray();
```